# ElasticSearch Query fields based on conditions on another field

Tags: elasticsearch

**Mapping**

```
PUT /employee
{
    "mappings": {
        "post": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "email_ids": {                    
                    "properties":{
                        "id" : { "type" : "integer"},
                        "value" : { "type" : "keyword"}
                    }
                },
                "primary_email_id":{
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
POST employee/post/1
{
    "name": "John",
    "email_ids": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "value" : "1@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "value" : "2@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "primary_email_id": 2 // Here 2 refers to the id field of email_ids.id (2@email.com).
    
}
```

I need help to form a query to check if an email id is already taken as a primary email?

eg: If I query for `1@email.com` I should get result as `No` as `1@email.com` is not a primary email id.

If I query for `2@email.com` I should get result as `Yes` as `2@email.com` is a primary email id for `John`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know with this mapping you can not achive what you are expecting.

But, You can create `email_ids` field as `nested` type and add one more field like `isPrimary` and set value of it to `true` whenever email is primary email.

**Index Mapping**

```json
PUT employee
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "email_ids": {
        "type": "nested", 
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "isPrimary":{
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "primary_email_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Document**

```json
POST employee/_doc/1
{
  "name": "John",
  "email_ids": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "1@email.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "2@email.com",
      "isPrimary": true
    }
  ],
  "primary_email_id": 2
}
```

**Query**

You need to keep below query as it is and only need to change email address when you want to see if email is primary or not.

```json
POST employee/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "email_ids",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "email_ids.value": {
                  "value": "2@email.com"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "email_ids.isPrimary": {
                  "value": "true"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```json
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.98082924,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "employee",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.98082924
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Interpret Result:**

Elasticsearch will not return result in boolean like `true` or `false` but you can implement it at application level. You can consider value of `hits.total.value` from result, if it is 0 then you can consider `false` otherwise `true`.

**PS:** Answer is based on ES version 7.10.